# How to deploy microservices in GCP?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

**What I have currently..**

... is an application with a microservices architecture, where the different services communicate with a gateway through GRPC, with the gateway serving REST endpoints.

I'm deploying this system on GCP. Currently, each service has a docker image with a GKE workload. So, each service is exposed with a public IP address and port. The gateway is also a Docker image on GKE, exposed with a public IP and port.

**What I want...**

... is the deployment to mirror my local deployment where each service communicates with the gateway through `127.0.0.1:{PORT}`, and only the gateway uses a public IP and port. What I hope to achieve is to restrict access to the services except through the gateway.

How can I get this done?

**NOTE**: I still want the services as separate Git repositories, so, having separate Dockerfiles/docker images.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding information provided I assume your "services" using dockerfiles are pods. Pods don't have external IP addresses.

You can use a [Load Balancer with Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) to add an external IP for the gateway pod.  For other pods, use [clusterIP service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) so that they are only exposed within the cluster and it allows you to specify what kind of service you want.